# Can I use my local server when connect through vpn

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn

I am clueless in this subject, so sorry if its a silly question.

I am working from home, connecting with vpn to the company server.

Internet is slow when using vpn, and I want to hear music with YouTube in my computer while working.

My simple question is: Is there anyway to use both my local network, and the remote network simultaneously? So I can use YouTube with my local network, while working with vpn.

Sounds to me that the answer is no, but I was surprised not once.. I am using Windows10 with cisco-vpn, if it can help to answer.

Thanks,
Shahar

Comment: Your company must enable this for you. Contact your IT department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

What you are looking for is "splitted tunneling".

The general idea is only when you need ressources located on company servers that you use VPN and any other ressource outside company net is downloaded via your normal Internet connection.

However I cannot tell if it is an option for you as it depends on what kind of VPN software you are running and how the security policy on your computer is managed when VPN is activated.

Comment: So I understand from that - It won't be silly to ask my company IT if their policy & software let this

Comment: No it won't. It might even be encouraged due to work from home might involve quite a few Zoom-meetings or or other video conference calls. Video uses a lot of bandwidth, so if it can bypass VPN connection it means more bandwidth for other necessary company traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can - but it's often disallowed/blocked by default for (mainly) security reasons, but you'll most likely have to get the guys & gals who manage the VPN to allow for it - for them to adjust the rules on their end.